# PySide clipboard error - object has no attribute .setText

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I'm using PyCharm to write my code (Python 3.4).
For some reason the following code returns the error:  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setText'

The code I'm writing will be run inside a program called Nuke. I've tested this code inside there and it seems to run fine. Copying things to and viewing the contents of the system clipboard.
From most of my googling it seems this is supposed to work. I haven't yet found any alternatives :(

It would be helpful if I could get this working in PyCharm!

```
from PySide import QtGui

cb = QtGui.QApplication.clipboard()

cb.setText("Yay") # set clipboard
print (cb.text()) # show current clipboard contents
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QApplication.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QApplication.clipboard):

> The PySide.QtGui.QApplication object should already be constructed
>   before accessing the clipboard.

The following code will work:

```
from PySide import QtGui
import sys

#construct app
app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

#then get the clipboard
cb = QtGui.QApplication.clipboard()

cb.setText("Yay") # set clipboard
print (cb.text())
```

Comment: Thank you!
Thats done the trick. :)

Do you know where I can go to learn more about constructing objects?